# Which of two methodologies is the correct one getting perf stats on a multi-threaded process?

Tags: linux, perf

I'm investigating the performance of a multi-threaded database sever. There is a particular workload that runs in roughly 61 seconds on a particular machine. The pid of the database process was 79894 when I ran perf against the workload.

In addition to the software threads in the database server, there are a number of Linux related threads, which are normally dormant on an idle system, that become active while my workload is running. Thus I want to use the -a option of perf as well as the -p option.

I run perf in 2 ways and get somewhat different results with each way.

The first ways I run the following perf command in one window

```
perf stat -p 2413 -a
```

and immediately run the database workload in another window. When the database workload finishes, I control C out of perf and get the following results

```
    Performance counter stats for process id '79894':

              1,842,359.55 msec cpu-clock                 #   30.061 CPUs utilized          
                 3,798,673      context-switches          #    0.002 M/sec                  
                   153,995      cpu-migrations            #    0.084 K/sec                  
                16,038,992      page-faults               #    0.009 M/sec                  
         4,939,131,149,436      cycles                    #    2.681 GHz                    
         3,924,220,386,428      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   79.45% frontend cycles idle   
         3,418,137,943,654      instructions              #    0.69  insn per cycle         
                                                          #    1.15  stalled cycles per insn
           402,389,588,237      branches                  #  218.410 M/sec                 
             5,137,510,170      branch-misses             #    1.28% of all branches  


     61.28834199 seconds time elapsed
```

The second method is to run

```
perf stat  -a  sleep 61
```

in one window and immediately run the database workload in another window.  After 61 seconds both perf and the workload finish and perf produces the following results

```
 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

      4,880,317.67 msec cpu-clock                 #   79.964 CPUs utilized          
         8,274,996      context-switches          #    0.002 M/sec                  
           202,832      cpu-migrations            #    0.042 K/sec                  
        14,605,246      page-faults               #    0.003 M/sec                  
 5,022,298,186,711      cycles                    #    1.029 GHz                    
 7,599,517,323,727      stalled-cycles-frontend   #  151.32% frontend cycles idle   
 3,421,512,233,294      instructions              #    0.68  insn per cycle         
                                                  #    2.22  stalled cycles per insn
   402,726,487,019      branches                  #   82.521 M/sec                  
     5,124,543,680      branch-misses             #    1.27% of all branches        

      61.031494851 seconds time elapsed
```

Because I used -a in both versions, I expected to get roughly the same results.

But with sleep,

```
cpu-clock is 2.5 times what you get with the -p version, 
context-switches are double what you get with the -p version  
and the other values are more or less the same
```

So 2 questions,

```
    (1) which set of results do I believe?
and 
    (2) how can there be more stalled-cycles-frontend than cycles in the sleep version?
```